# Prove that $\int_{0}^{1} \sqrt[3]{\frac{\ln (1+x)}{x}}dx \int_{0}^{1}\sqrt[3]{\frac{\ln^2(1+x)}{x^2}}dx<\frac{\pi^{2}}{12}$

Tags: calculus, inequality

> Prove that $$\int_{0}^{1} \sqrt[3]{\frac{\ln (1+x)}{x}}dx \int_{0}^{1}\sqrt[3]{\frac{\ln^2(1+x)}{x^2}}dx<\frac{\pi^{2}}{12}$$

My attempt,

By Holders inequality,

$$\int _{ 0 }^{ 1 } \sqrt [ 3 ]{ \frac { \ln { ( } 1+x) }{ x }  } dx<\left( \int _{ 0 }^{ 1 } \frac { \ln { ( } 1+x) }{ x } dx \right) ^{ \frac { 1 }{ 3 }  }\left( \int _{ 0 }^{ 1 } 1^{ \frac { 3 }{ 2 }  }dx \right) ^{ \frac { 2 }{ 3 }  }$$

and $$\int _{ 0 }^{ 1 } \sqrt [ 3 ]{ \frac { \ln { ^{ 2 } } (1+x) }{ x^{ 2 } }  } dx<\left( \int _{ 0 }^{ 1 } \frac { \ln { ( } 1+x) }{ x } dx \right) ^{ \frac { 2 }{ 3 }  }\left( \int _{ 0 }^{ 1 } 1^{ 3 }dx \right) ^{ \frac { 1 }{ 3 }  }$$

$$=(\int_{0}^{1} \frac{\ln(1+x)}{x}dx)^{\frac{2}{3}}$$

So, $$\int_{0}^{1} \sqrt[3]{\frac{\ln (1+x)}{x}}dx \int_{0}^{1}\sqrt[3]{\frac{\ln^2(1+x)}{x^2}}dx< \int_{0}^{1} \frac{\ln (1+x)}{x}dx$$

$$=\int_{0}^{1}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty } \frac{(-1)^{n-1}x^{n-1}}{n}dx$$

$$=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty } \frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n} \int_{0}^{1}x^{n-1}dx$$

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty } \frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n^2}$$

$$=\frac{\pi^{2}}{12}$$

Is there another way to solve this without using Holders inequality?

Comment: I think your third line we can get by Holder immediately.

Comment: You mean, like using [the Chebyshev inequality](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ChebyshevIntegralInequality.html) instead? I think @MichaelRozenberg is having what is sometimes called the reverse Hölder inequality in mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is. For example, we can look at numerical approximations for the two integrals that are at the same time upper bounds for these integrals and whose product is a lower bound for $\frac{\pi^{2}}{12}\approx0.822467$.

First, we remark that $f_1(x)=\sqrt[3]{\frac{\ln (1+x)}{x}}$ and $f_2(x)=\sqrt[3]{\frac{\ln^2(1+x)}{x^2}}$ are convex functions on the interval $[0,1]$ and continuous at $x=0$ by easy calculations of respective limits which give $f_1(0)=f_2(0)=1$.

Because of the convexity, for each $a\in[0,1]$ each integral is less than the area of the two trapezoid whose sommets are $(0,0),(0,1),(a,0),(a,f_i(a))$ and $(a,0),(a,f_i(a), (1,0),(1,f_i(1)$ where $i\in\{1,2\}$.

Calculation for $a=1$ (just one trapezoid for both $f_1$ and $f_2$)  does not give a good result (see at the NOTE below).

Trying with $a=0.5$ we have two trapezoids for each integral and THIS WORKS!

We have $$\int _{ 0 }^{ 1 } \sqrt [ 3 ]{ \frac { \ln { ( } 1+x) }{ x }  } dx\lt \frac{(f_1(0.5)+1)0.5}{2}+\frac{(f_1(0.5)+f_1(1))0.5}{2}=\frac{2f_1(0.5)+f_1(1)+1}{4}$$
$$\int _{ 0 }^{ 1 } \sqrt [ 3 ]{ \frac { \ln { ^{ 2 } } (1+x) }{ x^{ 2 } }  } dx\lt \frac{(f_2(0.5)+1)0.5}{2}+\frac{(f_2(0.5)+f_2(1))0.5}{2}=\frac{2f_2(0.5)+f_2(1)+1}{4}$$
The values to consider are $$f_1(0)=1;\space\space\space f_1(0.5)\approx 0.8696;\space\space\space  f_1(1)\approx 0.8854\\f_2(0)=1;\space\space\space f_2(0.5)\approx0.8109;\space\space\space f_2(1)\approx0.7832$$ which give

$$\int _{ 0 }^{ 1 } \sqrt [ 3 ]{ \frac { \ln { ^{ 2 } } (1+x) }{ x^{ 2 } }  } dx\lt 0.90615\\\int _{ 0 }^{ 1 } \sqrt [ 3 ]{ \frac { \ln { ^{ 2 } } (1+x) }{ x^{ 2 } }  } dx\lt 0.85125$$ Finally
$$\int_{0}^{1} \sqrt[3]{\frac{\ln (1+x)}{x}}dx \int_{0}^{1}\sqrt[3]{\frac{\ln^2(1+x)}{x^2}}dx\lt0.90615 \text{ x}\space0.85125=0.771360<\frac{\pi^{2}}{12}\approx0.822467$$
$$\space$$

**NOTE**.-*For $a=1$ we would have just a trapezoid but this easier calculation would give* $$\int_{0}^{1} \sqrt[3]{\frac{\ln (1+x)}{x}}dx \int_{0}^{1}\sqrt[3]{\frac{\ln^2(1+x)}{x^2}}dx\lt 0.84023$$ *and this bound is greater than $\frac{\pi^{2}}{12}$. Fortunately with the two given trapezoids the result is achieved (if it were not so, we would have to consider two values for $a$ inside the open interval $0\lt x\lt1$ and three trapezoids and so on until we got a good bound as desired).* *All this is just a numerical approximation of the integrals of course.*

[image]